# SP.ClientContext.get_current() is returning the wrong AD username?

Tags: javascript, user-profile, user-profile-service, spservices

I'm logged in as the following user `myintranet\svc_q_sp_farm`. The "About Me" page lists my details as `svc_q_sp_farm`, however the following CSOM/JavaScript code returns `Sharepoint\System` as the user. In addition the Javascript `SPServices` library also returns the same username, indicating that its not the following code, but something more sinister at work.

In reality I have one problem:

- How do I obtain the username `svc_q_sp_farm`?

However a related problem or question is why the system believes I'm a different user than the logged-in one (or at least has a different username for the current user).

```
function asyncGetUsername(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onUserQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onUserQuerySucceeded() {
    currentUserId=currentUser.get_loginName();
    conLog("query succeeded");
    window.isLoading=false;
    window.searchWait=0;
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    conLog("Failed in async call");
    conLog(sender);
    conLog(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the current user is part of the FARM ADMINISTRATORS group then the below code

```
currentUser.get_loginName()
```

will return `Sharepoint\System`. This is the expected behavior and you don't need to worry much. Try using a normal user account and you can see it returns the expected result.

Alternatively you can also use `currentUser.get_title()`

Comment: While this makes it harder to test, is undocumented for the get_loginName call and is also highly non-intuitive - this also seems to be the case. I was hoping that there was some way of getting hold of it, but appears to not be the case.  Thanks for the feedback Amal.  I believe this is the correct answer.